# Adding module to add files to a list

Tags: site-template

1. I added a module
2. The module is in the web feature
3. Now when I provision a site it tells me "The specified list does not exist". I am creating the list in the onet.xml
4. Now what to do?

This is from onet.xml

```
<List FeatureId="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" Type="101" Title="Customer Invoices" Url="CustomerInvoices" />
```

This is from the module element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="CustomerInvoices" Url="CustomerInvoices" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files\CustomerInvoices" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <File Url="Invoice and Payment Plan.xls" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="InvoiceandPaymentPlan.xls">
            <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x01010054A4D3DC99CB98468C7A59EBAC8B6376" />
            <Property Name="FileLeafRef" Value="Invoice and Payment Plan.xls" />
            <Property Name="ID" Value="1" />
            <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Document" />
            <Property Name="_ModerationStatus" Value="0" />         
            <Property Name="FSObjType" Value="0" />
            <Property Name="MetaInfo" Value="1;#Subject:SW|&#xD;&#xA;SPSDescription:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_parserversion:SR|12.0.0.6421&#xD;&#xA;vti_assignedto:SR|&#xD;&#xA;Keywords:SW|&#xD;&#xA;Owner:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedcustomprops:VX|vti_approvallevel vti_categories Subject SPSDescription vti_assignedto Keywords Owner vti_title _Author _Category ContentType _Comments Status&#xD;&#xA;vti_modifiedby:SR|NOV\\fainte&#xD;&#xA;ContentTypeId:SW|0x01010054A4D3DC99CB98468C7A59EBAC8B6376&#xD;&#xA;ContentType:SW|Document&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedtitle:SR|&#xD;&#xA;vti_title:SR|&#xD;&#xA;_Author:SW|NOV&#xD;&#xA;_Category:SW|&#xD;&#xA;_Comments:SW|&#xD;&#xA;Status:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_author:SR|NOV\\fainte&#xD;&#xA;vti_approvallevel:SR|&#xD;&#xA;vti_categories:VW|&#xD;&#xA;" />
            <Property Name="Order" Value="100.000000000000" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Do I need to put a reference in the onet.xml file if I want to provision a file?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like classic race conditions. Never use modules or list instances inside onet.xml as they are prone to race conditions.

Do you activate the module using feature stapling? If so, you have no guarantee that the list is provisioned when your features are activated.

Solutions could be either to move list instance out of onet.xml into a feature with an activation dependency to module, or to activate module in webprovisioned event (SP2010 only).

I always keep onet.xml as slim as possible, first thing to go is modules and list instances!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Url" attribute of your List Instance node in ONET.xml matches that of the one in your Module element.

Comment: Yes sir, they are identical. I updated my post to include source code from both onet.xml and module's element.xml

Comment: Does your list actually provision? Once you get the error message, navigate to http://your/site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx to see

Comment: I guess not. I am trying to find out which order a site template provisioned. You know what I am going to add files using object model. Thanks 4 ur help.

Comment: No worries. You could also just create the list using a ListInstance element alongside your Module element (not inside of, outside).